# Xcode skips firebase login completely after inputting all the code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have a swift file for both my sign ups and logins in storyboard but different view controllers of course... my issue is that when I run it nothing happens for example I get to my login screen and when I tap login it just takes me to my app's main screen without any information in the text fields. This happens whether I enter information on the screen or not. So my guess is nothing is going through at all which means it must be "skipping" all of this code. Sorry if that's the wrong term to use. I have my textfields connected to my IBOutlets and have Firebase imported into the project as well as this swift file. I am using Xcode 9.1 beta 2. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class SignUpandLoginController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func goWhenPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goLoginTabControl", sender: self)
}
@IBOutlet weak var myImageSignUpView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func importImage(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {
        //After it is complete
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        myImageSignUpView.image = image
    }
    else
    {
        //Error message
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var firstNameSignUp: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var lastNameSignUp: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var usernameSignUp: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var emailSignUp: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var passwordSignUp: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var retypePasswordSignUp: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLogin: UITextField! //!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordLogin: UITextField!  //!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIButton!

func action(_ sender: UIButton) {





    guard let username = self.usernameLogin.text else { return }
    guard let password = self.passwordLogin.text else { return }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in if user != nil
            {
                //Sign in successful
                print("SUCCESS")
            }
            else
            {
                if let myError = error?.localizedDescription
                {
                    print(myError)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("ERROR")
                }
            }
        })


//create user


Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: username, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in if user != nil
            {
                print("SUCCESS")
            }
            else
            {
                if let myError = error?.localizedDescription
                {
                    print(myError)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("ERROR")
                }
            }
        })
    }


self.firstNameSignUp?.delegate = self
self.lastNameSignUp?.delegate = self
self.usernameSignUp?.delegate = self
self.emailSignUp?.delegate = self
self.passwordSignUp?.delegate = self
self.retypePasswordSignUp?.delegate = self
self.usernameLogin?.delegate = self
self.passwordLogin?.delegate = self


}

//Hide keybaord when user touches outside keyboard
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Presses return key
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
textField.resignFirstResponder()
return(true)
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're probably showing/presenting the next screen using the button that is also connected to this `@IBAction` `@IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton)`.

What happens is that your program does not wait for the completion of your Firebase request, the sign up and sign in.

What you need to do is to disconnect the button to the next screen. Remove that `seque` and instead connect your **first view controller** to the **second view controller**, like in the image below:

[image]

After that, you give the `identifier` to the new `segue` you've just made. Then you will need to use the `perform Segue` function inside your **sign up successful block** and **sign in successful block**.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to disconnect the button that is basically the "login" button and drag the view controller to the main application view instead of the login button?

Comment: Correct. Disconnect the button that is `directly` connected to the second screen.  Then connect the first screen to the screen screen instead. Name their `segue`'s identifier to something and then inside your signin and sigup success blocks, put there the function `performSegue`.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question but how would I do a preformSegue inside the swift file? Sorry... I'm new at Swift.

Comment: You're doing correct in your screenshot. Then you will need to perform that segue. I think this tutorial will help you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRtcWqcvEME

Comment: So I have made a segue between the two controllers and have confirmed it to be working correctly but I still have no results... In my debug console it shows nothing about Firebase Auth and when I click login without any information in the text boxes it does the same thing it did before which is that it just takes me to my main page.

Comment: Hi @MattMech, edit your question and post your new codes there, I'll take a look at it. But here's what you need to do, put your `performSegue` only below your print("Success") in your signup and signin block. I hope you get it.

Comment: I know this sounds like another stupid question and I'm sorry about that but I know I can not have a IBOutlet under the viewDidLoad but how would I then link them? https://imgur.com/BfbXY8z

Comment: It's okay, soon let's start a chat in this thread if our conversation goes a bit longer. Anyways, you're almost there. You do not need to put IBOutlet under any function. You just call `performSegue` below your print success, and that's it!

Comment: Hello, I have done it all correct at least I think but nothing is happening currently which makes me feel like I have most likely missed a step. Also I would just like to thank you again for having the patience with me as I'm sure it must be hard for someone as skilled as you to have to explain simple things like this to me. This is what I have so far... https://imgur.com/hwAa8Lj and https://imgur.com/fwYtG1M